# getting a TypeError: 'module' object is not callable in the following python codes

Tags: python

I'm trying to make a game using pygame, but I'm stuck with an error and I don't know what the problem is.

Error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\EDX\python\Rocket\Rocket.py", line 114, in <module>
    run_game()
File "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\EDX\python\Rocket\Rocket.py", line 91, in run_game
    new_bullet = Bullet(Display_setting(),
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\EDX\python\Rocket\Rocket.py", line 51, in __init__
    self.rect = pygame.rect(0, 0, Display_setting.bullet_width
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

```
import sys
import pygame
from pygame.sprite import Sprite
from pygame.sprite import Group

class Display_setting():
    def __init__(self):
        self.bullet_speed_factor = 1
        self.bullet_width = 3
        self.bullet_height = 15
        self.bullet_color = 60, 60, 60

class Bullet(Sprite):
        #I get the error here
        self.rect = pygame.rect(0, 0, Display_setting.bullet_width
                                , Display_setting.bullet_height)
        self.rect.centerx = rk.rect.centerx
        self.rect.top = rk.rect.top
        self.y = float(self.rect.y)
        self.color = Display_setting.bullet_color
        self.speed_factor = Display_setting.bullet_speed_factor

def run_game():
    while True:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                sys.exit()
            elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
```

This is where i'm trying to use the 'Bullet' class:

```
new_bullet = Bullet(Display_setting(),
                    display_screen,
                    rk)
```

Comment: In the `Bullet` class the code should go inside a function.

Comment: sorry, could you maybe elaborate a bit more ?

Comment: The code in the ```Bullet``` class should be inside an __init__ method (like the code in the ```Display_setting``` class).